# How is this Stack Overflow Careers ad NOT promoting discrimination?

Tags: discussion, jobs, legal, offensive, bias

I clicked on this link just out of curiosity and was reading through it when I ran across this line -

> If you love digital media and Jesus, show us what you can do!

How is this different from discriminating for other protected reasons such as race, familial status, etc... -

> If you love digital media and aren't Asian, show us what you can do!
>
> If you love digital media and do not have children, show us what you can do!

Is this type of advertisement supported?  Should it be?

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/54376/front-end-web-developer-the-christian-broadcasting?a=14jFXW3yU

**Isn't this technically illegal??** - http://www.eeoc.gov/policy/docs/qanda_religion.html

Comment: I don't think they require "loving Jesus" as a must. I believe they will also hire, gasp, a Jewish person. They are just trying to be creative and/or funny in my opinion. If you find it offensive you can probably contact the company itself and ask them to change the wording. They won't, but nobody is stopping you from asking. :)

Comment: They will *not* however, hire Asian parents. You gotta draw the line somewhere.

Comment: Whether or not they are requiring it is irrelevant, it is an advertisement and is governed by laws which state you can't discriminate in hiring practices.  Would it be funny if it said 'and aren't black'?

Comment: How dare they discriminate against people that don't love digital media.  I hate digital media with a passion, but I should still be actively encouraged by them to work for them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How did I make that assumption?  I asked how it is different from other forms of discrimination

Comment: It is a **Christian** organisation, for goodness sake.

Comment: @PWKad So if you showed up to a Church asking for a job as a priest you would expect equal considerations even if you were Muslim?

Comment: @Servy You are asking a question that is irrelevant and off topic - all people are protected from discrimination - http://www.eeoc.gov/policy/docs/qanda_religion.html

Comment: @PWKad Great, now read the `2. Are there any exceptions to who is covered by Title VII’s religion provisions?` section.

Comment: I was going to point that out, @Servy. Dangit!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We've discussed listings like this in the past. It's not illegal unless they literally say they only are willing to hire people of a particular faith.

It's not discriminatory to want to hire employees that are going to be a good cultural fit; they're not saying they aren't going to hire a non-Christian. It's more of a "don't apply here if you have a problem with our faith".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if you could link to previous discussion that may be helpful.

Comment: When I say we've discussed, I mean internally at the company.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 17):

I see no discrimination here.

This is a job advert for a *religious organisation*. They want everyone that aligns with their ideals to apply.

Other adverts ask you to be passionate about their business goals, this advert is looking for people passionate about their religious beliefs.

Note that the US EEOC law [explicitly exempts religious organisations](http://www.eeoc.gov/policy/docs/religion.html#_Toc203359493) from equality rules based on religion:

> C. Exceptions
>   1. Religious Organizations
>
> Under Title VII, religious organizations are permitted to give employment preference to members of their own religion.

If you do find a listing you have a problem with, feel free to either [contact the Careers 2.0 team](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/support) or the company directly.

Comment: EEOC Law states "Disparate treatment violates the statute whether the difference is motivated by bias against or preference toward an applicant or employee due to his religious beliefs"

Comment: @PWKad "Religious Organization Exception: Under Title VII, religious organizations are permitted to give employment preference to members of their own religion."

Comment: So based on this answer if a religious organization that supported hate or other controversial topics wanted to post career adverts on here they should be allowed or is it only for Christian organizations?

Comment: @PWKad: Why not study the law yourself?

Comment: @PWKad They wouldn't be legally prohibited from doing so.  SE is of course free to determine which advertisements they wish to provide on their site.  There is no low preventing discrimination of what advertisements one allows on their own sites.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am no lawyer and cannot give advice related to the law, neither can you, I brought up a question that I felt was important trying to look for answers.  Good to know how welcoming the community over here at Meta is, have fun estranging new users...

Comment: @PWKad: I am sorry you feel enstranged; all I did was ask some direct questions; I am [Dutch](http://stuffdutchpeoplelike.com/2011/05/28/dutch-directness/), if that makes a difference.

Comment: Playing the Dutch card again I see .... *high five*

Comment: @Bart: I am always slightly baffled when people tell me I am being rude..

Comment: `<kidding type="totally">`@MartijnPieters Maybe the "always" thing should be a hint there ;)`</kidding>`

Comment: @MartijnPieters You know its rude to complain about people telling you that you're being rude.

Comment: @Servy: You know it's rude to tell people it's rude to complain about people complaining about being told that you are being rude!

Comment: @PWKad Re hate etc: You've inaccurately generalised from "love Jesus" to being hateful or controversial - the law is quite clear: a primarily religious organisation like a temple or the Christian broadcaster here are allowed to give preference to (choose to employ) candidates on grounds of their religion. However, "The exception does not allow religious organizations otherwise to discriminate in employment on protected bases other than religion, such as race, color, national origin, sex, age, or disability" so don't worry about churches being allowed to say "Hate the elderly? Work for us."!

Comment: @AndrewC And you have come in hours after I posted a link to a document and we all looked at it and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: @PWKad My mistake - I assumed Martin had posted the link I followed, and your comments very much gave me the impression you were not feeling the consensus - perhaps saying so on the comments would indicate you had come to the same conclusion better than the current accusations of irrelevance and causing estrangement do.

Comment: @AndrewC Thanks for your comment and suggestions of how I should comment / act when on Meta.StackExchange.com.  I regret ever posting here thanks to you and your fellow members such as Martijn and apologize for trying to explain why or even engage in discussion with you.  Sorry for wasting all of your precious time by engaging in discussion in a discussion forum!  Enjoy upvoting and +1 each other!

Comment: @PWKad You wanted a discussion but didn't want me to point out problems I perceived in what you were saying or how you were saying it?

Comment: I genuinely didn't get from what you said that you felt it was OK for SE to host an ad inviting Christians to apply for this job at a Christian broadcaster, and I genuinely thought you felt doing so was somehow equivalent to racism and other hate, and that you were worried that this exemption allowed religious organisations to practice all forms of discrimination. My initial comment disagreed with those things and backed it up with quotes from the law we were discussing and added an example I found amusing. I don't apologise for being hours late; it's not a chat room and I was at work earlier.

Comment: You might be interested in [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying); it helped me out when I was upset after my first post on meta.